# rosbridge 2.0 limit bandwith

Tags: ros, rosbridge, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using rosbridge to have a web-based user interface with my robot.
As some of the message I want to check are published quite fast, the amount of CPU and bandwith required is high.
There is any option to limit the bandwith or the refresh rate?
I'll be happy receiving only one every four messages or something similar.

I'm using ROS hydro and Ubuntu 12.04.

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204919/rosbridge-2.0-limit-bandwith/) by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2015-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the `throttle_rate` parameter in roslibjs (https://github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/develop/src/core/Topic.js#L21). This will place a delay between messages inside of rosbridge and decrease bandwidth.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2015-03-17**:
I've changed the default throttle_rate from 0 to 200 and now messages are displayed much slower. However, I think that the data transmitted between the robot and the website is still the same. Is there any other "throttle_rate" like param for the rosbridge webserver?

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-03-17**:
`throttle_rate` is sent directly to rosbridge server, no throttling is done client side. Passing this parameter through the client should have rosbridge limit the rate at which is sends that topic across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of a way to do this within ros bridge itself, but you could perhaps use something like [topic_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools), and then specifically the [drop](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/drop) or [throttle](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/throttle) nodes.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [narcispr](https://answers.ros.org/users/1214/narcispr/) on 2015-03-17**:
topic_tools throttle works fine. However, it is a pity that I've to republish all the topics that I want to include in my interface (this means one extra node for each topic). Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-17**:
Yes, that is an unfortunate requirement. The only other option I see is changing the publication rate at the source, but that might not be an option with many nodes.